# How to display value of a field from a different table by using the value of a different column in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I realize the heading is a little confusing but my problem is quite simple. I hae two models in my rails 5 app. User and Expense. Each expense belongs_to a user. I have an index page where all expenses are being listed. I can list the user IDs for each expense from the expenses table but I want to instead look up the name of the user (in column username) in the users table and display it with the expense instead. The view I have written is below. But it doesn't work.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Teamjournals</h1>

<table style="padding: 2px; width: 50%" border="2px" align="center">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><%= link_to new_expense_path, :class =>"btn btn-success btn-wide" do%>Add New Expense<% end %></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Expense Date</th>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Expense Amount</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @expenses.each do |expense| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= User.joins(:expense).where('expense.user_id = ?', @user.id) %></td>
        <td><%= expense.expense_date %></td>
        <td><%= expense.currency.currency %></td>
        <td align="right"><%= expense.expense %></td>
        <td><%= expense.description %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What are your models like? Do you have relation between User and Expense - i.e. User model `has_many :expenses` and Expense `belongs_to :user`

Comment: your models please. Doing joins in your views isn't good practice, do it in a helper module and test the relationship separately, when that is ok try using the attributes from the joined table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so in your iteration over `@expenses` you have this line:

```
<%= User.joins(:expense).where('expense.user_id = ?', @user.id) %>
```

you can change it to this:

```
<% user = expense.user %>
```

Note that I'm using `<%` not `<%=` because I'm just trying to assign a variable, not print the output to html.

Then after defining `user` you can say `<%= user.name %>`.

You should read a bit more about active record associations, but here's a few side comments about the query you've shown

```
User.joins(:expense).where('expense.user_id = ?', @user.id)
```

In this case, you should use the method generated by `belongs_to` instead of writing a query. But in situations where you do want to write a custom query, you should only be using `where` when you want to get an array. In this case you're looking for a single record so you could use `find_by`. Furthermore, the joins you're doing here is unnecessary

```
 # any of these works
 user = User.where('id = ?', expense.user_id).first
 user = User.where(id: expense.user_id).first
 user = user.find_by(id: expense.user_id)
```